# ajax post call to mvc controller with antiforgery token and json object gives me error 500

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send antiforgery token and json object via ajax call

here is my ajax call method

```
    $("button#submit-btn").on("click", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       //var valid = $("form#sh-post-form").valid();

       var modell = { PlaceId: 1 };
       var token = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

       $.ajax({
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Post/SaveSharePost",
           data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, model: JSON.stringify(modell) }
    });
```

and here is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveSharePost(SharePostVM model, string retunrUrl = null)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);
        return View(model);
    }
```

When I try to send the ajax call, it gives me internal error 500 and the error message says "The required anti-forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present"

How can I fix it?

Thanks guys

Comment: `data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, PlaceId: 1 }` and remove the `contentType` option (or else its `data: JSON.stringify({ __RequestVerificationToken: token, PlaceId: 1 }),` (you cannot mix the content types). But why are you not using `$('form').serialize()` to serialize all the inputs including the token?

Comment: so basically I can't send object and antifogery token? How can i do with $('form').seriallize()??

Comment: Of course you can (as per the first comment - the token just needs to be part of the object). And `$('form').serialize();` serializes all your form controls within the form tag including the token.

Comment: @StephenMuecke um as per your first comment, I need to send model object not "PlaceId: 1" the object will have more variables

Comment: I know! Just include `__RequestVerificationToken: token` as part of the object. But again, why not just use `.serialize()`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke so when I do like  data: JSON.stringify({ model: modell, __RequestVerificationToken: token }) It gives me same error

Comment: That is NOT what I told you to do!

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah I know but I need to send object not the variable PlaceId: 1 itself.

Comment: @StephenMuecke and I just tried with your suggestion the second suggestion exactly the same, but It still gives me same error sorry..

Comment: I know - For the 3rd time, your object just needs to include the token `var model = { PlaceId: 1, AnotherProperty: 'xxx', YetAnotherProperty: 'yyy', __RequestVerificationToken: token }` and `data: model,` (without the `contentType` option)

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh I got it sorry man

Comment: But if you have generated you view correctly, - ie its `@model SharePostVM` and you have used the strongly typed `Html.Helper` methods to generate your form controls - e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PlaceId)` then its just `data: $('form').serialize(),`

Answer (score 0):

you should just addd forgery token to your model like:

```
model.__RequestVerificationToken=token
```

and

```
$.ajax({
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       dataType: "json",
       type: "POST",
       url: "/Post/SaveSharePost",
       data: {model: JSON.stringify(modell) }
});
```